# Why do time-consuming operations in `lifecycleScope.launch` block the UI thread?

Tags: android, io, kotlin-coroutines, android-viewmodel, android-database

I read list of pages from database and display on `RecyclerView`. It looks like this:

ViewModel:

```kotlin
@HiltViewModel
class BookDetailViewModel @Inject internal constructor(
    savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle,
    private val bookRepository: BookRepository,
    private val chapterRepository: ChapterRepository,
) : ViewModel() {
    private var currentResult: Flow<PagingData<Chapter>>? = null

    val bookID: Long = savedStateHandle.get<Long>(BOOK_ID_SAVED_STATE_KEY)!!

    val book = bookRepository.getBook(bookID)

    suspend fun getChapters(): Flow<PagingData<Chapter>> {
        val lastChapterID = book.first().lastChapterID
        val newResult = chapterRepository
            .getChapters(bookID, lastChapterID)
            .cachedIn(viewModelScope)
        currentResult = newResult
        return newResult
    }

    companion object {
        private const val BOOK_ID_SAVED_STATE_KEY = "bookID"
    }
}
```

And ChapterListFragment:

```kotlin
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        ...
        ...
        
        load()

        return binding.root
    }
    private fun load() {
        // Make sure we cancel the previous job before creating a new one
        queryJob?.cancel()
        queryJob = lifecycleScope.launch {
            viewModel.getChapters().collectLatest { result ->
                binding.hasChapters = true
                adapter.submitData(lifecycle, result)
            }
        }
    }
```

However, when opening `ChapterListFragment`, there is a short period of lag, which is obviously stuck.

I think this is caused by the operation of reading the database in the `viewModel.getChapters` method, but I do it in a coroutine, and I don't understand why there is still a lag.

The `ProgressBar` associated with `binding.hasChapters` is not displayed.

If I add a `Thread.sleep(2000)` to the `getChapters` method, then the `ChapterListFragment` will be opened with a delay of two seconds.

So I have two questions：

**1. Why is this happening?**

My original understanding was that the code executed in `lifecycleScope.launch` does not block the current UI thread, but now it seems that this is not the case.

**2. How do I properly refresh my list?**

***EDITED***

I use the following code, then opening `ChapterListFragment` becomes smooth:

```kotlin
    private fun load() {
        // Make sure we cancel the previous job before creating a new one
        queryJob?.cancel()
        queryJob = lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            Thread.sleep(300)
            withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                viewModel.getChapters().collectLatest { result ->
                    binding.hasChapters = true
                    adapter.submitData(lifecycle, result)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I first blocked the IO thread for 300ms, which is the animation time required to open the `Fragment`, so it does not block the UI thread, and the `ProgressBar` can be displayed normally. Then get the paging list in the main thread (UI thread) and refresh it, there is no lag.

**But I think this way is not good, I should not actively block for 300 milliseconds, and then go to fetch the list.**

Comment: Have you tried moving the `load()` call to `onViewCreated`? Also, `withContext` is not required as you are not returning any result.

Comment: Yes, I tried it. But the result is the same as in `onCreateView`.

Comment: Facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

A few things to consider here.

1. It's better only to inflate a `View` in the `onCreateView` so it gets inflated as fast as possible.
2. Do other View-related work after the inflation in `onViewCreated`.
3. You are using `withContext` which is not required as it is similar to `async {...}.await` which is used to return something after some processing inside the block. (That 'could' cause a delay, not sure though)

Since you are using a `Flow` where you have to handle the lifecycle, you can do something like this:

```kotlin
// Follows the inflated view's lifecycle
viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch {
    // repeatOnLifecycle is a suspend function
    viewLifecycleOwner.repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.STARTED) {
        viewModel.getChapters().collectLatest { result ->
            binding.hasChapters = true
            adapter.submitData(lifecycle, result)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The `repeatOnLifecycle` method could not be found.

Comment: Add `lifecycle-runtime-ktx` dependency.

Comment: I imported the `lifecycle-runtime-ktx` package and it works now. But there is still lag, not smooth enough, and the result is the same as before the modification.